# Click on button in ng-dialog is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have HTML page called instructions.html. When I click on the button in this page, it should naivgate to quiz-list.html and opens ng-dialog with a "Start quiz" button. When I click on this button, the pop up should disappear and start the quiz. But the click on the button is not happening.

Below is the instructions.html page.

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="KbcQuizController">
    <div class="instructions-container">
        <div class="instructions-heading">
            <span class="header-text"> Rules </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>1. Persons must enter the Competition on their own behalf and
                entry(ies) by proxy will not be accepted, even for their family
                members.</p>
            <p>2. An entry/ies is not transferrable.</p>
            <p>3. The Company or the Producers will not entertain any claims
                / questions / queries with respect to the authenticity or
                correctness of any questions and answers for the questions asked in
                any round of the Competition.</p>
            <p>4. The Company’s decision on the correctness or incorrectness
                of any answer is final and binding on all Contestants.</p>
            <p>5. Use of mobile phones will not be permitted during the
                shoot, and during the Auditions. It may lead to disqualification.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="next-container">
            <button class="next-button btn btn-primary" ng-click="getWelcomePage()">Start Quiz</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
(function() {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.kbcquiz').controller('KbcQuizController',KbcQuizController);

    KbcQuizController.$inject = [ '$timeout', '$rootScope', '$scope', '$http','$filter', 'ngDialog', 'usSpinnerService', 'quizService', '$state' ];
    function KbcQuizController($timeout, $rootScope, $scope, $http, $filter,ngDialog, usSpinnerService, quizService, $state) {
        console.log("quizService is::" + quizService);
        $scope.count = 1;
        $scope.timer = {
            value : 60
        }

        var stopped;

        $scope.startTimer = function() {
            stopped = $timeout(function() {
                console.log($scope.timer.value);
                $scope.timer.value--;
                $scope.startTimer();
                if ($scope.timer.value == 0) {
                    alert("timeout");
                }
            }, 1000);
        };

        $scope.stop = function() {
            $timeout.cancel(stopped);

        }

        $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.timer.value = 60;
        }

        $scope.startQuiz = function() {
            console.log("in start quiz");
            quizService.getQuestion($scope.count).then(null, function(err) {
                console.log("error in get question");
            });
            $scope.startTimer();
        }

        $scope.getWelcomePage = function() {
            $state.go('quizpage');
            ngDialog
                    .open({
                        template : 'app/modules/kbcquiz/welcome.html',
                        className : 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                        controller : KbcQuizController,
                        controllerAs : 'vm',
                        scope : $scope,
                    });
        }

    }

})();
```

Here is my module:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var module = angular.module('app.kbcquiz', [ 'ui.router','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination', 'ng-bootstrap-datepicker','ngDialog', 'angularSpinner' ]);

    module.config(appConfig);

    appConfig.$inject = [ '$stateProvider' ];

    function appConfig($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider.state('app.kbcquiz', {
            url : '/rules',
            templateUrl : 'app/modules/kbcquiz/instructions.html',
        })

        .state('quizpage', {
            url : '/app/kbc-quiz',
            templateUrl : 'app/modules/kbcquiz/quiz-list.html',

        });

    }
})();
```

And here is my welcome.html:

```
<h3 class="dialog_header">Welcome to KBC!!</h3>
<div class="dialog-contents" ng-controller="KbcQuizController">
    <div class="ngdialog-message">
        <div>
            <div class="next-button">
                <button type="submit"
                    class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary"
                    ng-click="startQuiz(); closeThisDialog('button')">Start Quiz</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. Because when I click on button in ng-dialog it is not even going to startQuiz() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with this code. Please check a working sample at  http://embed.plnkr.co/nNMsoxHgP1ZUPizf8nIY/

- you do not need a type='submit' button unless you're indeed posting some data. In your case a type='button' is sufficient. This doesn't cause any problem though.

  ```
  <button type="button" class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary" 
          ng-click="startQuiz(); closeThisDialog('button')">Start Quiz
  </button>
  ```
- Your ngDialog call is one problem. The controllerAs syntax is not applicable to your code, and you do specify the controller in the welcome page. So the following is enough:

  ```
  ngDialog
  .open({
          template : 'welcome.html',
          className : 'ngdialog-theme-default'
  });
  ```
- Another problem is that you declare a state called `app.kbcquiz`. This actually means you should have a state called app, and kbcquiz would be a nested state of app. For the sample, I just renamed the state to `instructions`

  ```
  $stateProvider.state('instructions', {
      url : '',
      templateUrl : 'instructions.html'
  })
  ```

I did a few other adaptations, just for the sample to work (i.e. urls, removed missing dependencies). Please check it out :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using button type as submit and there is no form tag in your code.
Use a form tag and then implement it.

```
<form ng-submit="startQuiz(); closeThisDialog('button')">
<h3 class="dialog_header">Welcome to KBC!!</h3>
<div class="dialog-contents" ng-controller="KbcQuizController">
    <div class="ngdialog-message">
        <div>
            <div class="next-button">
                <button type="submit"
                    class="ngdialog-button ngdialog-button-primary">Start Quiz</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried giving the form tag as you mentioned above and checked. It is not working.